# How can we manage ProductVersion(A Windows Resource) automatically?

Tags: windows, winapi, resources, versioning

Windows resources have a FileVersion and a ProductVersion.

In native development environment(eg. Win32 app, device driver)
How do you manage the ProductVerion automatically?

My language is c/c++. And I use Visual Studio 2008.

I want to increase the version automatically when I build my projects.

Is it possible?
I guess there is a simple(and good) way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language/development tool do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this integrated [VS2008 plugin](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/IncVersionVC8.aspx) on CodeProject that adds the version and product information to your C/C++ application.

Comment: Thanks tommieb. It looks nice :)

Comment: Is there anyone who knows better plugin?